# Is there any way to paint that circle gradient

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, paint

I am trying to make something similar to LED diode in Java ( I extend JPanel and override paint method ). I draw cicrle in center of panel with radius =20px ( green on, red off). Is there any way to paint that circle gradient ( darker in rcenter and lighte at edge ) ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes: use a [RadialGradientPaint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/RadialGradientPaint.html) to draw the circle.